# Add a button to a results column in NetSuite Saved Searches

Tags: netsuite

How can I add a button to a results column of a Saved Search?

I have a workflow that adds a button to ITEM records when a certain field is updated. When clicked, the button initiates another workflow.

Is it possible to bring this button into a Saved Search column as a link. When a user clicks the link, it will initiate the button action. This would similar functionality as the 'GRAB' button in Case Management.

Answer (score 0):

Needs more info to answer fully, but in short: yes, you can.  You can create a text formula to build an anchor element to create a link - for example, below is a formula you can use to place a Print Label link on each row of an item search:

```
'<a href="/app/accounting/print/barcodeprinter.nl?itemid=' || {internalid} || '">Print Label</a>'
```

You will still need to create the conditions under which it displays (possibly using a `CASE` statement) and build the url with the correct path and parameters, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a step in the right direction. How would I go about finding the correct URL to use? The button is generated through a workflow action.

Comment: Inspect the button with dev-tools and look for the on-click action.

Comment: I've inspected the button and pasted the code below. Can you help me create the the link? This is my first time doing this: onclick="try{NS.Workflow.buttonClick('custpageworkflow668');}catch(e){document.location = addParamToURL(addParamToURL(addParamToURL(document.location.href,'workflowbutton','668'),'workflowbuttoninstanceid','10235697'),'workflowbuttonobsoletehandling','T');}; return false;"

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, however, it would be fantastic if a NetSuite guru could assist with getting this requested workflow button link functional.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button to a Saved Search Result Column using a Formula (Text) field and entering a formula something like below:

```
'<button onclick="window.open(`/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=123&deploy=1&rec_id=' || {internalid} || '`);">Do Action</button>'
```

The above would put an actual button on the screen that would open a Suitelet to perform the action and write some response page. If you wanted it to stay on that page, you could do something with an xhr request, like below:

```
'<button onclick="var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open(`GET`, `/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=123&deploy=1&rec_id=' || {internalid} || '`); xhr.onload = function(oEvent) { var response = JSON.parse(xhr.response); if (xhr.status == 200 && response) { console.log(xhr.response); window.open(`https://system.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/estimate.nl?e=T&id=` + response); } else { console.log(xhr.response); alert(`Issue Doing Button Action`) } };xhr.send(null);this.style.display = `none`;this.parentElement.append(`Button Clicked`);">Do Action</button>'
```

In both cases, you would need to update the url there to the appropriate url for your Suitelet. In your case, you would want to create a Suitelet that uses the N/workflow module to initiate or trigger your second workflow.

To handle the "when a certain field is updated" part, you could do a case statement, something like this:

```
CASE WHEN {custbody_your_field} IS NULL THEN 'No Action Available' ELSE '<one of the code snippets above>' END
```

And don't forget the END statement :)

A sample Suitelet to initiate a workflow:

```
define(['N/workflow'], function (wf) {
    /**
     * Initiates a workflow
     * 
     * @NApiVersion 2.x
     * @NScriptType Suitelet
     * @author Stephen Lemp (SuiteRep)
     */
    var exports = {};

    var WORKFLOW_ID = 1234;
    /**
     * @function onRequest Definition of the Suitelet script trigger point.
     * @governance XXX
     * 
     * @param {Object} params
     * @param {http.ServerRequest} params.request The incoming request.
     * @param {http.ServerResponse} params.response The Suitelet response.
     *
     * @return {void}
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function onRequest(context) {
        var rec_id = context.request.parameters.rec_id
        var workflowInstanceId = wf.initiate({
            recordType: 'some_record_type', // The record type that the workflow is deployed on.
            recordId: rec_id, // The record ID of some record.
            workflowId: 'customworkflow_some_workflow'
        });
    }

    exports.onRequest = onRequest;
    return exports;
});
```